# Cross-domain validation in PHP

Tags: php, validation

I am currently working on a project that revolves around the following:

Page 1 ( domain1 ) redirecting to Page 2 ( domain2 ) redirecting to Page 3 ( domain2 )

I wanna make sure that the Page 2 contents is NOT shown unless the user is confirmed to have visited Page 1 first. For obvious reasons, I cannot use sessions and cookies, since domain1 and domain2 are two separate domains.

$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] is a possible solution, but it can be modified or even stripped from the browser requests, so I have no guarantee I won't inadvertently block legitimate users by using it.

How would I go about doing it?

Comment: Can you controll redirect params? You can set variable - hash to validate data or based on some user params.

Comment: Yes, I can. There are no forms or user parameters on Page 1 - it's got some other functions, and a redirect to Page 2. Care to elaborate how I could set this hash variable?

Comment: "it's got some other functions" - what is it about? Can you modify redirection from page1 to page2 with param, like http://page2/?token=hash_function($salt,$user_ip)?

Comment: Yes, I could do that - great idea. So basically I take the user IP, hash it, and send it as a token in the URL? Then in page 2 I hash the IP again, and compare the result to the value in the token part of the visiting URL?

Comment: Yes. Is is bad for you - if user can "cheat" by using token second time?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You cannot set cookie without direct request from browser.

You can pass a token while redirecting from http://page1 to http://page2/?token=hash_function($salt,$user_ip).

More complex way is to generate token on domain with page1 and recheck it with direct request from page2 server to page1 server. This allows you to create "one-time" tokens and even user changed his ip during session (really rare case) - this redirect still be valid.